# Excess newline in grouped table cells in ConTeXt TABLE

Tags: tables, context

I have a table in ConTeXt. It has fixed width. The first row has some grouping. And I get strange extra newline in there. I can tell the text perfectly fits yet there is this extra space.

Here is my code:

```
\setuppapersize[A4]

\startdocument


{\bTABLE[width=.2\textwidth]
\bTR \bTD[nc=2]  Vasdasdsa asdasdasdsda asda \eTD \bTD[nc=2] Vasdasdsa asdasdasdsda asda \eTD \eTR
\bTR \bTD sdeefdf \eTD \bTD sdeefdf \eTD \bTD sdeefdf \eTD \bTD sdeefdf \eTD \eTR
\eTABLE}

\stopdocument
```

Here is what I get:
[image]

Why this is happening and how to prevent this?

I have a lot of very complex tables with fancy colorful designs. I am tasked to implement them with a TeX-like markup language to auto-generate PDFs in batches. I was trying to use LaTeX and faced lots of issues. So I tried ConTeXt thinking it may be more robust. It feels like I am doing something wrong. I used to use HTML/CSS a lot. With CSS I could have implemented this long ago.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  It's very likely that this is caused by the space between the last `asdf} \eTD` and the extra space was just too wide to fit on the line, going instead to a visually blank line below.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I tried removeing it and I even removed one 'asda' word at the end of both cells. Yet the problem is still there. I suspect that `\definedfont` requires some form of termination to properly recalc line heights/widths but don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due to an interference caused by `width=0.2\textwidth`. I don't completely remember the algorithm used by ConTeXt for determining height and width of the table, but what is happening is that the height of the cell is calculated before `nc=2` is applied (or that is how it appears to me).

To work around that, add `width=fit` (which is the default value) for cells where you specify `nc=2`. So, the following works (and continues to work correctly when the first line does not fit in a single line):

```
\starttext

\bTABLE[width=0.2\textwidth]
\bTR 
  \bTD[nc=2,width=fit] Vasdasdsa asdasdasdsda asda \eTD 
  \bTD[nc=2,width=fit] Vasdasdsa asdasdasdsda asda \eTD 
\eTR
\bTR 
  \bTD sdeefdf \eTD 
  \bTD sdeefdf \eTD 
  \bTD sdeefdf \eTD 
  \bTD sdeefdf \eTD 
\eTR
\eTABLE

\stoptext
```

Comment: It solves the problem for a moment. However if I start using `setupTABLE`  to change widths of individual columns then it starts crumbling apart again. It starts to work fine again if I set width of every cell and stop using `setupTABLE`.

Comment: Could you post a minimal example showing the issue